# low power circuit design in verilog and calculate power for different input sequences

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, synopsys-vcs

I want to implement the following circuit in verilog. FA is the full adder circuit and trapezoidal shape is a mux. I am not sure how to add this power gating pmos in the circuit. 
And also I would like to synthesize the circuit in Synopsys Design vision and compute the difference in power when **APP is 0 and 1**.

[image: FA=Full Adder]

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks

Farhana

Comment: What is the expected behavior for On and Off of PMOS on FA ?

Comment: Seems like the PMOS is acting like a power switch to give supply to the FA when the gate is at low level, at the same time it is selecting the FA outputs as inputs for both muxes.

Comment: PMOS will act as a power switch. When APP=1, FA block will be off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design two versions of the original circuit: one of them will assume the power switch is ON and the FA is operating. The other one will assume the power switch is OFF and then, the FA will be missing from the circuit. Leave the remaining devices (eg. muxes) on both circuits and set APP acoordingly.

Tell Synopsys to not perform any optimizations (it would remove the muxes as the select input is fixed to a certain value, but if it does so, the current compsumtion of the muxes, although neligible, wouldn´t be taken into account).

Perform a power analysis on both versions and you will get the difference in power.

The result you obtain will have to assume that the leakage current through the PMOS device is 0 when OFF

Comment: In some literature I have found that power consumption for the circuit when APP=0 is ~2uW but ~0.01uW for APP=1. What my understanding is, when App=0,1 FA and 2 MUXs will contribute to the power. But when APP=1 there is still 2 MUXs present. Then how the value is so low?  This can be true only if Synopsys prunes out the MUXs when APP=1.
Can you please explain the result?

Comment: This is using two different circuits or using only one circuit with the power switch to the FA?

Comment: If APP is 1, transistors involved in switchings are only those from the MUXes. If APP is 0, you have to add all transistors within the FA. A typical implementation for a FA has one 3-input XOR gate, 3 2-input AND gates and one 3-input OR gate, while a typical 1-bit mux has one 2-input OR, 2 2-input AND and one inverter. How many transistor does each component have? How many of them are actually involved in a state switch whenever A or B change?

Comment: They have not mentioned how they implemented the circuit.
For mirror FA, total 28 transistors are required. And for a MUX, 12 transistors are required. There are two MUXs. for rough calculation I assumed power ratio will be **Power(APP=1)/Power(APP=0)=(12+12)/(28+12+12)=0.46**. But the result shows the ratio is almost 0.005. Do I need to enumerate the all the switching conditions to obtain the power values?